# the background-image for the pizza hut logo is not showing up

Tags: html, css, background-image

I've tried to make a pizza hut logo appear in the center of the navigation bar but the image does not appear can you please help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title>replit</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style>
header{
margin:auto;
text-align:center;
}
li   {
display: inline-block;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 20px;
}
header nav ul li .logo a{
text-indent: -9999999px;
background-image:url("https://media.cnn.com/api/v1/images/stellar/prod/190625084159- 
20190625-pizza-hut-logo-new.jpg?q=x_3,y_0,h_1684,w_2993,c_crop/h_270,w_480");

}  
</style>
</head>
<body>
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Menu</li>
      <li class="logo">
        <a href="index.html">pizza hut logo</a>
      </li>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Location</li>
    </ul>
 </nav>
 </header>
 <section>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>b</div>
  <div>c</div>
 </section>
 <footer></footer>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I've been trying to debug this for a while and I still could not find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS selector is wrong.  This:

```
header nav ul li .logo a
```

Should be this:

```
header nav ul li.logo a
```

By having the space between `li` and `.logo`, you're actually looking for child of `li` with the class of `logo`.  What you actually want is `li` elements that have the class `logo` themselves, which is `li.logo`.

Comment: The selector is wrong,  yes. However, it doesn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would set the `background-image` on `logo` and can use relative positioning to put it where you desire. Also, I set your `li.logo` to have `margin: 0;` Finally, `ul` elements have default margin at block-start and block-end of 1em. So I set your `ul` to `margin: 0;` so it doesn't appear offset. See the CSS changes I made below.

```css
header{
margin:auto;
text-align:center;
}
li   {
display: inline-block;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 20px;
}
.logo {
  background-image: url('https://media.cnn.com/api/v1/images/stellar/prod/190625084159-20190625-pizza-hut-logo-new.jpg?q=x_3,y_0,h_1684,w_2993,c_crop/h_270,w_480');
  background-position: cover;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100px;
  height: 67px;
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title>replit</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Menu</li>
      <li class="logo">
        <a href="index.html"></a>
      </li>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Location</li>
    </ul>
 </nav>
 </header>
 <section>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>b</div>
  <div>c</div>
 </section>
 <footer></footer>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
 </body>
 </html>
```